# Nitrogen6x running timesys demo won't accept keyboard input

Tags: linux, shell, ubuntu, serial-port, embedded

I have connected the serial console port to my computer using a serial cable (not serial to usb if that makes a difference). When I go through the standard boot procedure described here -> https://linuxlink.timesys.com/docs/gsg/i.MX6QSABRELite I get to the end but I am unable to enter commands.

I am running Ubuntu 12.04 and using minicom (although I have tried screen and cu as well as putty on windows).

**Procedure:**

I run `minicom -s` (I have tried this as root and not as root)
I configure the connection so that minicom will:

```
look in /dev/ttyS0
run at a speed of 115200 8N1
has no hardware flow control
has no software flow control
```

I then save this as default. When I run minicom the GUI confirms these settings.

Then when I reset the board (unplug power and then plug power back in) I start to get some output. At one point the output says that I am to press any key to abort the "auto boot process". Once I try and press the any key the countdown continues and then it begins the auto boot process. Once it finishes booting it says that I can enter `help` in order to view a list of built-in shell commands. When I do so nothing happens (unless I turn local echo on in which case I can see help being typed but really that does nothing more than make me feel better).

I am also unable to press `Ctrl-A Z` to get a help screen, I have tried pressing all three at the same time, Ctrl-A followed by Z, Ctrl-A then Ctrl-Z but nothing comes up. And in order to exit minicom I need to kill the process.

The minicom output can be found here https://gist.github.com/rkillam/9935517.

**What I've tried:**

I have tried restarting the board with and without the provided sd card. The scenario above describes the results when booting with the card. When booting without the board cannot find the 6x_bootscript and then proceeds to run some kind of U-boot shell, which I still cannot interact with.

I have tried booting with and without an ethernet cable connected to the board. Both scenarios end the same except when done without the cable there are more error messages that relate to the fact that it can't lease an ip.

I have tried booting with an HDMI connection. When the board is connected to a monitor the timesys demo starts up. I can interact with this demo (via mouse and keyboard) but when I click the "Exit Embedded Demo" button it green screens and then takes me back to the demo.

I have also tried manually echoing and reading to/from the device (as per the instructions here -> http://serial-lines.blogspot.ca/2011/04/for-this-post-were-going-to-send-some.html). But nothing was ever returned when I read from /dev/ttyS0. I tried:

```
echo "help" > /dev/ttyS0
echo -e "help\n" > /dev/ttyS0
```

But neither resulted in anything. I tried these manual echoes both while connected and not connected to the board using minicom.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you are just interacting to the board using serial connection. Have you tried connecting the keyboard to the USB port on the board?

My guess is if connecting a keyboard to the USB port doesn't work, the problem may be in the boot-script and you need an update.

you can also try using "picocom" command to interact with the board.
you first need to change the permission though.

```
sudo chmod 777 /dev/ttyS0
```

and then connect to the board (you may need to install picocom on your system first)

```
picocom -r -b 115200 /dev/ttyS0
```

I haven't use  minicom, but in case of picocom you must change the permission to be able to interact.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem with u-boot and solved it by disabling hardware handshaking (which you appear to have done) and by switching to cutecom as an alternative to minicom.